# File 'root/lib/getLibs.ps1' in gradle 3.5.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I update gradle plugin to 3.5.0 in my android studio I got a error **File 'root/lib/getLibs.ps1' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.** When I generate signed bundle apk , how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of including the implementation file that makes the file work.

Here's what you have to do:

1. Find the `.jar` that has a folder named `lib`.
2. Use a zip program (I used Zip 7) to extract the `jar`.
3. Rename the folder (and any references to it, if need be)
   (I renamed my folder from `lib` to `libs`).
4. Put the whole folder in Java's `bin` folder and turn it from a regular folder to `.jar`. (Look up folder to jar if you don't know how).
5. Smack that new `.jar` in you project.